How to obtain the coordinates of an element (text) within a PDF?
I am developing a method to parse a PDF, identify where an article begins and ends within a PDF, and then save it to a new PDF with only this content found. However, the problem arises when I have two articles on a single page. Where using the DevExpress library, I cannot find a method to make this separation. Currently, I am trying to do this with the "PDF Graphics API," but it would be necessary to know the coordinates of this article. However, I have not found a way to obtain these coordinates. If anyone can help me, I would greatly appreciate it.
using DevExpress.Pdf;
using DevExpress.Pdf.Native;
using System.Drawing;

//...

namespace DivisorPDF
{
    public class PdfManipulator
    {
        public void Pdf(string sourcePdfPath, string outputPdfPath)
        {
            string searchedText = "attachment";

            using (PdfDocumentProcessor processor = new PdfDocumentProcessor())
            {
                processor.LoadDocument(sourcePdfPath);
                string pageText = processor.GetText(); 

                PdfPage page = processor.Document.Pages[0];
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}



@kj, "My question is... With the DevExpress library, how do I extract a part of the PDF and save it in another document without losing the formatting? I've tried several methods, but haven't found any."

The PdfTextSerchResults class will provide you with Rectangles property containing the location of your text.
Here's a GitHub sample showing the searching for, and highlighting, of text within a Pdf: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/pdf-document-api-highlight-search-results/tree/333301890fe6700326efc61e5d304b12351bf95f

"I studied the document you sent me through the link, but I still haven't been able to do what I needed. What I need is to find chapters or articles within a PDF, as desired, and separate them into distinct pages. However, when there are 2 chapters on a single page, I am unable to divide them into two pages. Do you have any ideas on how I can do this?"

If you're able to find the range, I believe you should be able to pull the text of the paragraph. From there, I would simply create a new PDF document and insert the text into each page as required.

"It's exactly what I thought, but I don't know how to capture the range between the first Chapter and the second. I imagine I would have to work with coordinates, but throughout the documentation, I couldn't find the right way to implement it. I've been searching for long days."

Have you tried the DevExpress support center? They should be able to steer you in the right direction if you open a ticket.
